# How to return the values from columns, using the data from another column in Python

Tags: python

If I have a dataframe with this structure with Column `H` containing corresponding column headers:

[image: Input]

How can I generate an output with Column `I` having the corresponding values:

[image: Output]

Comment: Hello @StijnH and welcome to Stack Overflow! What kind of dataframe do you have? Is it a pandas-DataFrame or a list of lists for example? A few lines of your code would be also helpful to have.

Comment: Please avoid posting pictures. Instead try to copy your table/dataframe here. Thank you

Comment: Could you tell us how did you form this `I` column?

Comment: It is a pandas-Dataframe. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: The code should generate column I

Answer (score 0):

I think the third row should be `y,c` not `c,s`. If that's the case, then you can do that in just one line like so:

```
df.apply(lambda x: f"{x['B']},{x['C']}" if x.name%2==0 else f"{str(x['A'])},{x['B']}", axis=1)
```

And here is the full example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ "A": [1, 5, 6, 7],
                    "B": ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
                    "C": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                    "D": ['q', 'r', 's', 't'],
                    "H": ["B,C", "A,B", "C,D", "A,B"]})

df['I'] = df.apply(lambda x: f"{x['B']},{x['C']}" if x.name%2==0 else f"{str(x['A'])},{x['B']}", axis=1)
print(df)
#   A  B  C  D    H    I
#0  1  w  a  q  B,C  w,a
#1  5  x  b  r  A,B  5,x
#2  6  y  c  s  C,D  y,c
#3  7  z  d  t  A,B  7,z
```

Comment: Was that what you were asking for??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've a pandas dataframe `df` with 0 indexing, the following should do the trick:

```
df['I'] = 0
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
  df['I'].loc[i] = ','.join(df[df['H'].loc[i].split(',')].loc[i])
```

Comment: with this second code, @Eeshaan I receive this error: typeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.int64 found

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['I'] = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x[x.H.split(',')])), axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   A  B  C  D    H    I
0  1  w  a  q  B,C  w,a
1  5  x  b  r  A,B  5,x
2  6  y  c  s  C,D  c,s
3  7  z  d  t  A,B  7,z
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do a one-liner with list comprehension, but I couldn't figure it out. Instead, I did half of the work with list comprehension and the other half with a loop:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,5,6,7],
                'B': ['w','x','y','z'],
                'C': ['a','b','c','d'],
                'D': ['q','r','s','t'],
                'H': ['B,C','A,B','C,D','A,B']})
df['I'] = np.empty((len(df), 0)).tolist()
n=0
for i in df['H'].apply(lambda x: [df[y] for y in x.split(',')]):
    for j in i:
        df.iloc[n,5].append(j[n])
    n+=1
df
```

output:

```
    A   B   C   D   H    I
0   1   w   a   q   B,C  [w, a]
1   5   x   b   r   A,B  [5, x]
2   6   y   c   s   C,D  [c, s]
3   7   z   d   t   A,B  [7, z]
```